# Is there a function that help using a private struct

Tags: c++, struct, private

I need a function that can enter a private struct

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct abc {
    private:
        int a;
    }b;

    int main(){
        //i want to use the variable a
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of it being private if you want to access it?!

Comment: I agree, what's the point. But if you want to access the `a` vairable then the only ways are with a method of `abc` or with a function declared as a friend of `abc`. You will get a much better answer if you explain **why** you want to do this.

Comment: `struct a { int a; }` and then `((a*)&b)->a = 42` should do it.

Comment: @DeiDei that would be undefined behaviour - casting objects to be things they're not might look like it works, but even if they have the same members the compiler may have optimised them differently.   Better would be to have `struct a{int a;};  struct abc: private a{};`   (also - answers are below so that people can down vote them)

Comment: Do you have access to `abc` definition ?

Comment: @DeiDei why not `struct a { int a; }` and then `b.a = 42;` ? :P

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Off-topic: It's not the task of a console application to keep a console window open, so you shouldn't do stuff like `system("pause")`, `getchar` or `std::cin >> ...`. All you achieve this way is that your programme won't be usable in scripts (there's no-one to hit any key). Instead, just open a console window manually (cmd.exe) and start your programme from within.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will break the encapsulation.

If you need to read the variable `a` you create a getter:

```
struct abc {
int getA() const;
private:
    int a;
};
```

if you need to modify the variable you should create a setter:

```
struct abc {
void setA(int);
private:
    int a;
};
```

There is a way use [`friend` function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_friend_functions.htm) but I don't advice you to do this.

If it is a `struct` consider making `a` public if you need access and no encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow a specific class/struct or function to access private member, use the `friend` declaration. This is normally only used for closely related things, so as to not make the members accessible to everything elsewhere (in other languages, things like `internal` are similar).

```
struct abc {
private:
    int a;
    friend int main();
};

void foo(abc &x) {
    x.a = 5; // ERROR
}
int main(){
    abc x;
    x.a = 2; // OK
    foo(x);
    //i want to use the variable a
    system("pause");
}
```

Frequently if you want read-only access, a "getter" will be used, e.g.

```
struct abc {
    int get_a()const { return a; }
private:
    int a = 45;
};

int main() {
    abc x;
    std::cout << x.get_a(); // OK
}
```

And for read-write a get and set function. The set function may do extra validation, or other logic.

```
struct abc {
    int get_a()const { return a; }
    void set_a(int x)
    {
        if (x % 2) throw std::invalid_argument("abc must be even");
        a = x;
    }
private:
    int a = 45;
};

int main() {
    abc x;
    x.set_a(50);
    std::cout << x.get_a();
    x.set_a(51); // throws
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The private fields and methods should not be accessed by anyone but the class that declares them. However there are situations where it is needed. For example if you wanted to serialize/print your struct. For these cases you can declare a function or another class with a `friend` keyword. So for example:

```
struct abc
{
private:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const abc &s);

    int a;
};
```

You would then implement the function with the same signature `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const abc &s);` somewhere and it would have access to `abc::a`:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const abc &s)
{
    return stream << s.a;
}
```

This would allow using your struct for example with `std::cout`.

Note that there are not many genuine cases like this one and you should avoid using `friend` as much as possible. In this case for example a getter method would do the same thing and you would avoid the whole problem without breaking encapsulation.

Comment: @Aconcagua Right you are. :-) Edited.